# make combinations from one column of a data.table and sums from corresponding

Tags: r, data.table

In:

```
   V1  V2
1:  A 0.6
2:  B 0.3
3:  C 0.1
```

Out (V1 are the combinations, and V2 their sum):

```
   V1  V2
1: AA 1.2
2: AB 0.9
3: AC 0.7
4: BA 0.9
5: BB 0.6
6: BC 0.4
7: CA 0.7
8: CB 0.4
9: CC 0.2
```

Achieving this with a double for loop, which seems slow... any faster, data-tablish, way of speeding things up?

Script:

```
dtIn <- data.table(LETTERS[1:3], c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1))
dtOut <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(dtIn))
  for (j in 1:nrow(dtIn))
    dtOut[[paste0(i, j)]] <- data.table(paste0(c(dtIn[i, V1], dtIn[j, V1]), collapse = ""),
                                        dtIn[i, V2] + dtIn[j, V2])
dtOut <- rbindlist(dtOut)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double-loop suggests the use of `outer` here:

```
dtIn[,list(outer(V1,V1,paste0),outer(V2,V2,"+"))]

#    V1  V2
# 1: AA 1.2
# 2: BA 0.9
# 3: CA 0.7
# 4: AB 0.9
# 5: BB 0.6
# 6: CB 0.4
# 7: AC 0.7
# 8: BC 0.4
# 9: CC 0.2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CJ` to "cross join" each column with itself:

```
dtIn[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
  Reduce(if (class(x)=="character") paste0 else `+`, CJ(x,x)))]
```

This has a few advantages vs `outer`:

- It doesn't involve coercion of a matrix (from `outer`) back to a vector.
- It doesn't require repeatedly typing the var names.
- If `dtIn` columns have names (other than the defaults), they will be preserved.
- It can be extended fairly cleanly (e.g., `CJ(x,x,x)` to get 3x combinations).

.

---

In base, this can be done with `expand.grid`, which is essentially the same as `CJ`:

```
DF = data.frame(dtIn)
data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) 
  Reduce(if (class(x)=="character") paste0 else `+`, expand.grid(x,x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be faster as it's a pure data.table implementation.

```
> library(data.table)

> aTbl = fread("A 0.6
+ B 0.3
+ C 0.1")

> aTbl[, .SD
+      ][, ind := 1
+      ][, .SD[.SD, on='ind', allow.cartesian=T]
+      ][, `:=`(V1 = sprintf('%s%s', V1, i.V1), V2 = V2 + i.V2)
+      ][order(V1)
+      ][, .(V1, V2)
+      ]
   V1  V2
1: AA 1.2
2: AB 0.9
3: AC 0.7
4: BA 0.9
5: BB 0.6
6: BC 0.4
7: CA 0.7
8: CB 0.4
9: CC 0.2
>
```